# Guardar varios campos con un mismo submit

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, base-de-datos

Quiero hacer un programa donde pueda insertar varios campos con un mismo submit, en diferentes registros. El problema es que la cantidad de estos campos es indefinida ya que se crean en base a un Foreach. Cada campo debe tener un respectivo ID dependiendo del orden, para que puedan ser asociados con campos de otra base. Se entiende mejor si muestro de que va la aplicación.
[image: Esta es la aplicación que estoy diseñando]

Como ven, lo que quiero es que al presionar el submit, cada input sea un registro diferente, con su respectiva fecha (que será común para los tres) y respectivo "objetivo" (con su Id). Los "objetivos" también varían ya que son construidos mediante un Foreach.
A continuación les dejo el código que se me había ocurrido, pero que no funciona...

INDEX.BLADE.PHP:

```
    <table class="table">
    <tr>
            <th>Fecha</th>
        @foreach($objetivos as $obj)
            <th>Objetivo {{$obj->id}}</th>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
    <tr>
        {!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action'=>'objetivosController@store']) !!}
                <td>{!!Form::date('fecha')!!}</td>
            @foreach($objetivos as $obj)
                <td>{!!Form::time('tiempo')!!}</td>
                <td>{!!Form::hidden('obj_id','{{$obj->id}}')!!}</td>
            @endforeach
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">{!!Form::submit('Agregar datos de hoy')!!}</td>
    </tr>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        foreach($request->tiempo as $req){
            objetivosApp::create([
                'fecha'   => $req['fecha'],
                'obj_id'     => $req['obj_id'],
                'tiempo'   => $req['tiempo'],
            ]);
        }
    }
```

**PD: Todavía soy nuevo en esto de la programación, disculpen si ven algún error muy grosero... por favor no duden en preguntar si es que me expliqué mal**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando dices "pero que no funciona", tendrías que aclarar qué es lo que no funciona. ¿Que sucede cuando haces el submit?¿Se guarda algo en la BD? Si es así ¿Se guarda solo uno?¿Cuál?

Comment: Dado que no manejo Laravel no puedo darte una respuesta concreta, pero como sugerencia puedo decirte que no queda claro cual es el problema que tuviste.

Comment: El problema es que al presionar el submit, la página se recarga, pero no se guarda nada en la base de datos! Es extraño porque en el método Store() no tengo ningún redirect como para que vuelva a recargar la página, pero tampoco veo fallas en el código

Comment: ¿Tienes los atributos `fecha`, `obj_id` y `tiempo` en el array `$fillable` del modelo `objetivosApp`?¿Es `obj_id` su llave primaria o es otra columna?

Comment: Si, tengo todas esas propiedades en el $fillable de objetivosApp. Y no, obj_id no es llave primaria, es otra columna! Quizás el problema es que está mal planteado lógicamente y debería hacerlo de otra forma...

Comment: Ok, última duda. ¿Tiene timestamps la tabla de objetivosApp?¿O sea tiene las columnas created_at y updated_at?

Comment: Si! Tengo ambas! Las dudas no molestan, gracias por el interés!

Comment: Estaba leyendo el mensaje que habías posteado justo cuando se eliminó! Esto se debe a algo en especial?? Parecía muy útil!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por un lado, si envías los inputs con el mismo nombre, en el controlador sólo recibirás el último input de cada nombre. Para enviar un array debes nombrarlo como array. Por ejemplo `{!!Form::date('tiempo[]')!!}` en vez de `{!!Form::date('tiempo')!!}`. Puedes leer más en [¿Cómo creo arrays en un form de HTML?](https://www.php.net/manual/es/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays) .

Entonces en el formulario hazlo así:

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'route' => 'objetivos.store']) !!}
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Fecha</th>
        @foreach($objetivos as $obj)
            <th>Objetivo {{$obj->id}}</th>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            {!!Form::date('fecha')!!}
        </td>
        @foreach($objetivos as $obj)
            <td>
                {!!Form::time('tiempo[]')!!}
                {!!Form::hidden('obj_id[]', $obj->id)!!}
            </td>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">{!!Form::submit('Agregar datos de hoy')!!}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Luego en el controlador, nota cómo sería la representación de los inputs si los pasas a una array con el método `$request->all()`:

```
array:4 [▼
  "_token" => "TVy4tUgFdocg69nFooDZehs75c3uAyvIlDRbFaF5"
  "fecha" => "2020-06-06"
  "tiempo" => array:3 [▼  // este es sobre el que iteras
    0 => "12:00"  // tiene tres claves 0, 1 y 2; que en en el foreach le llamaremos $key, y cada clave tiene un valor, que en el foreach le llamaremos $value
    1 => "13:00"
    2 => "14:00"
  ]
  "obj_id" => array:3 [▼ // sobre este no iteras, por lo tanto deberás acceder primero por la clave "obj_id"
    0 => "1" // y luego por la misma clave $key, para que coincida con la clave 0, 1 o 2 del array sobre el que estás iterando
    1 => "2"
    2 => "3"
  ]
]
```

Entonces podrás iterar sobre el array para insertar los valores en base de datos.

Siguiendo la línea de lo que estabas haciendo, con el método `create()`:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    foreach($request->tiempo as $key => $value){
        objetivosApp::create([
            'fecha' => $request['fecha'], // fecha es siempre la misma
            'obj_id' => $request['obj_id'][$key], // aquí deberás indicarle el índice que coincida con el del input sobre el que estás iterando
            'tiempo' => $value, // este es el input sobre el que iteras, así que solo asígnale el valor
        ]);
    }

    redirect()->back()->with('success', 'ok');
}
```

O algo menos intenso para la base de datos usando `insert()` en vez de `create()`. Nota que `insert()` no autocompleta las columnas `created_at` y `updated_at`, así que tendrás que agregarlas tú mismo, preparando los datos antes de insertar:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = [];
    foreach($request->tiempo as $key => $value){
        $data[] = [
            'fecha' => $request['fecha'],
            'obj_id' => $request['obj_id'][$key],
            'tiempo' => $value,
            'created_at' => now(),
            'updated_at' => now(),
        ];
    }
    objetivosApp::insert($data);

    redirect()->back()->with('success', 'ok');
}
```

No olvides que tu función debe tener un return, le agregué uno para que redirija hacia atrás con un mensaje, pues no pusiste uno tú en la pregunta. Puedes agregar en la vista el siguiente código para ver el mensaje:

```
@if(session('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {!! session('success') !!}
    </div>
@endif
```

---

Viendo lo que agregaste de las rutas, también ahí tienes un problema, pues las rutas resource debe llevar una uri para que de allí tome el nombre (de las rutas y los parámetros). Agregale la uri:

```
Route::resource('objetivos', 'objetivosController');
```

Y en el formulario usa el nombre `objetivos.store` de la ruta para que la solicitud sea enviada al controlador y método correctos:

```
'route' => 'objetivos.store'
```

Puedes leer más sobre esto en la documentación de Laravel:

[Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers).

Otras referencias:

Laravel Collective [Opening A Form](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.0/html#opening-a-form).

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar, únicamente recarga la página. Quizás tenga un error en la sintaxis del formulario, pero yo no noto nada raro... probe simplificando el formulario a uno normal y corriente sin Foreachs, y aún así no funciona. Donde me puedo estar equivocando?

Comment: Si, esta enlazado ya con una ruta. Quizas sea la insatalción de laravel Collective. Utilizé el comando composer require laravelcollective/html en GitBash en el directorio de la aplicación, tengo que hacer algo más?

Comment: Utilizé el comando Route::resource('/', 'objetivosController'); en el web.php, y según el Git la ruta es App\Http\Controllers\objetivosController@store

Comment: La URI del metodo Store me dice que es '/'

Comment: |        | POST      | /        | store   | App\Http\Controllers\objetivosController@store   | web        |

Comment: Ya lo cambie por 'route'=>'store' y sigue sin funcionar, en la publicación agregué una foto del route:list. Estaba pensando que quizás serviría evitar el laravell Collective porque a lo mejor ahi está el error, probaré con eso

Comment: Tienes un problema con las rutas, mejor agregale la uri como te dije `Route::resource('objetivos', 'objetivosController');` y en el formulario deja `'route' => 'objetivos.store'`.

Comment: Excelente, no solo funcionó sino que lo hizo a la perfección, te agradezco muchisimo por todo el tiempo que me dedicaste, si alguna vez me encuentro en la capacidad de compensarte no voy a dudar en hacerlo. Ahora voy a analizar el problema a ver si yo también entiendo cual estaba siendo mi fallo

Comment: Disculpame, te puedo consultar acerca de la array multidimensional en la función Store? Es que llevo un rato y no la logro comprender...

Comment: Es que no entiendo en que momento se guardó una array dentro de otra, o cual es el valor que te da si llamas al Request... no comprendo porque no funciona solamente 'obj_id' => $request['obj_id']

Comment: Agregué a la respuesta un ejemplo de cómo se vería el request con algunos comentarios a ver si se entiende mejor. A lo que preguntas concretamente "porque no funciona solamente 'obj_id' => $request['obj_id'] ", es porque `request['obj_id'] ` tiene los tres valores, sería un array así : `[
    0 => "1"
    1 => "2"
    2 => "3"
  ]`, entonces debes indicarle cuál de esos tres es el que coincide con el del otro array `"tiempo" => [
    0 => "12:00"
    1 => "13:00"
    2 => "14:00"
  ]`, si es el 0, el 1 o el 2.

Comment: Ya lo entendi! Mil gracias!